# compare two different date ranges sales in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, sqlite, t-sql

I want to compare two different date ranges sales in two columns.. I am using query below but its giving wrong sales.. please correct my query

```
select s1.Itm_cd,s1.Itm_Name,Sum(S1.amount),Sum(s2.amount) 
from salestrans s1,salestrans s2 
where s1.Itm_cd = S2.Itm_cd 
and S1.Tran_dt between '20181101' and'20181130'
and S2.Tran_dt between '20171101' and '20171130' 
group by s1.Itm_cd,s1.Itm_Name 
Order by s1.Itm_cd
```

Comment: Please provide schema, sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want conditional aggregation here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        s1.Itm_cd,
        s1.Itm_Name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN s1.Tran_dt BETWEEN '20181101' AND '20181130'
                 THEN s1.amount ELSE 0 END) AS sum_2018,
        SUM(CASE WHEN s1.Tran_dt BETWEEN '20171101' AND '20171130'
                 THEN s1.amount ELSE 0 END) AS sum_2017
    FROM salestrans s1
    GROUP BY
        s1.Itm_cd,
        s1.Itm_Name
)

SELECT
    Itm_cd,
    Itm_Name,
    sum_2018,
    sum_2017,
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(sum_2017, 0) <> 0
         THEN FORMAT(100.0 * (sum_2018 - sum_2017) / sum_2017, 'N', 'en-us')
         ELSE 'NA' END AS growth_pct
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    Itm_cd;
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys..  Tim I applied your suggested conditional aggregation and  got the correct result, Thank you so much... I also want to add column to show  growing % can you help in that please..

Comment: @shahzadalam Answer updated. I recommend using a CTE here, because otherwise you would have to repeat big ugly `CASE` expressions, and the query would not very readable.

Comment: Used above code for Growth % but shows error - Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: Corrected using Nullif

Comment: @shahzadalam I edited my question per your comment.  I think we should check for both a `NULL` and a zero 2017 sum.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
select s1.Itm_cd,s1.Itm_Name,Sum(S1.amount),Sum(s2.amount) 
from salestrans s1,salestrans s2 
where s1.Itm_cd = S2.Itm_cd 
and Convert(Varchar(10),S1.Tran_dt,112) between '20181101' and'20181130'
and  Convert(Varchar(10),S2.Tran_dt,112) between '20171101' and '20171130' 
group by s1.Itm_cd,s1.Itm_Name 
Order by s1.Itm_cd
```

Here the logic is that in right side while comparision you are providing only date and not any separator and time. The same way should be applied to the column in left side for comparision.

```
if(Convert(Varchar(10), getdate(),112) = '20181224')
  print 'Matched'
else
  print 'Not Matched'

if(getdate() = '20181224')
   print 'Matched'
else
  print 'Not Matched'
```

Here the output is `Matched` for first and `Not Matched` because in first case both side same format has been taken for comparison.